Как отключить появление полос прокрутки в MDI-интерфейсе?
При перетаскивании дочерних окон за пределы области главного окна (даже чуть-чуть) появляются полосы прокрутки. Так и не смог найти свойство, которое отвечает за их появление. Подскажите, пожалуйста, три момента, связанные с ними:

Как можно их отключить, чтобы они не появлялись вовсе?
Как включить их "на постоянку" - чтобы они не появлялись когда им вздумается, а были видны всегда? Тоже может пригодиться.
Можно ли управлять скоростью их появления? Т.е. не мгновенно как по-умолчанию (потому что это вызывает глюки), а плавно, например, в течение одной секунды.

Заранее спасибо!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6458535/12888024

@aepot Благодарю за ответ, но это не то что нужно. Вопрос в вашей ссылке про то, чтобы оставить окна всегда в пределах родительского окна. Мне же нужна возможность размещать окна за его пределами, т.к. управление их видимостью будет осуществляться с помощью изменения зума. Полосы прокрутки только отвлекают, и по факту никогда не будут использоваться.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944450/12888024

Спасибо, работает! Осталось теперь понять, как именно...)))
